# Thu axle mount for bike lugage rack

Tags: rack, through-axle

I would like to mount a luggage rack on a bike that has no mounting holes and a thru axle.
Is there an adapter that I can use to replace the thru axle with something that provides attachment points?

My bike: Trek Domane SL-5 gravel, with disk brakes and a 12 x 1.75 x 160 mm thru axle.

Comment: Other options include P-Clips and the Thule Pack,n,Pedal style racks.

Comment: Would you consider employing a framebuilder to modify your frame with some fixings?  Nutserts would do it but its a matter of finding a good spot in the frame to add them without compromising strength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. We try to avoid specific product recommendations here, but in this case, I know of only one option, from the [Robert Axle Project](https://robertaxleproject.com/cargo-rack-thru-axles/). Please note that this looks like a real PITA when you need to remove the rear wheel.

There are a few racks designed to use the rear wheel's quick release as a mounting point, but I haven't seen any of these updated for through axles. If one were adventurous, one might try milling out the openings in the mounting plates or fabricating new ones. Again, inconvenient whenever you need to remove the rear wheel.

[image: From linked website]

Comment: Great find - I've pulled in an image from the linked web site, in case they ever vanish.

Comment: The downside however when adding a rack to a bike that wasn't intended to carry one are the possible negative effects on stability and load limits. If the frame is carbon, I wouldn't add a rack.

Comment: Thanks, I've ordered an axle from the Robert Axle Project.